# javafx button.onclick() not working

Tags: javafx

i am having a problem when i click on the button it doesn t work.
actually for the moment i am just asking that the button execute a system.out.println() just for the test. the name of the button is btndetailUser

```
    listRechercheUser.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<User>, ListCell<User>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<User> call(ListView<User> p) {
            ListCell<User> cell;
            cell = new ListCell<User>() {

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(User user, boolean bln) {
                    super.updateItem(user, bln);
                    if (user != null) {
                        ImageView img;
                        String mm=user.getPath().trim();
                        if (mm.equals("fusee.png")){
                        img = new ImageView(new Image("mto/cr/images/"+mm));}
                        else{
                        img = new ImageView(new Image("mto/cr/images/mains-fonds.png"));

                        }
                        VBox vb = new VBox(10);
                        HBox hb = new HBox(20);
                        VBox vb1 = new VBox(20);
                        VBox vb3= new VBox(20);
                        vb1.getChildren().add(new Label("               "));
                        hb.setStyle("-fx-border-color: #C8C8C8 ;");
                        vb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                        VBox vb2 = new VBox(30);
                        vb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                        vb2.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
                        vb3.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
                        Label id = new Label(user.getId()+"id firas:");
                        Label username = new Label(user.getUsername()+" username firas:");
                        Label nom = new Label(user.getNom()+"nom firas:");
                        Label prenom = new Label(user.getPrenom()+"prenom firas:");
                       Button btndetailUser = new Button();
                        btndetailUser.setId("btndetailUser");
                         btndetailUser.setText("btndetailUser "+user.getId());
                         Image imageAccesProjet = new Image("mto/cr/images/enter.png");
                        ImageView enterIV= new ImageView(imageAccesProjet); 
                        enterIV.setFitHeight(10);
                        enterIV.setFitWidth(10);
                            btndetailUser.setGraphic(enterIV);
                           btndetailUser.getStyleClass().add("buttonLogin");

                        System.out.println(btndetailUser.getText());
                           btndetailUser.setOnMouseClicked(
                                   (MouseEvent event2) ->
                                                              System.out.println("firas"));
                           btndetailUser.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                            @Override
                            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                                System.out.println(".handle()");
                            }
                        });


                       vb.getChildren().addAll(new Label("  "), img, new Label(" "),username);
                        vb2.getChildren().addAll(nom, prenom);
                        vb3.getChildren().addAll(btndetailUser);
                        hb.getChildren().addAll(vb1, vb, vb2,vb3);

                        setGraphic(hb);
                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like,

```
btndetailUser.setOnAction(e -> {
    System.out.println("freetext")
});
```

Comment: What method within your code are you putting it in? Really the button click should be in your 'start' method so make sure that it is being read by the code?